# How to access global data using laravel8 function in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hello everyone I have a function called me in laravel 8. I can see the data coming from this function on every page, but I cannot do anything with this data. Since I can't use this data, I have to call it again every time. This is unnecessary at the moment. How can I access the data returned from this function?

Api.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MemberController;
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.verify'], static function($router){
 Route::get('me', [MemberController::class, "me"]);
});
```

MemberController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Member;

public function me(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(auth()->user());
}
```

My Vuex file I created to use the data

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    user: {}
},
getters: {
    user: state => state.user,
},
mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user;
    },
},
actions: {
    getUser({ commit }) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/me", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
                },
            })
                .then(result => {
                    commit('setUser', result.data);
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error.response && error.response.data.message || 'Error.');
                });
        });
    },
}
});
export default store;
```

my computed

```
    computed: {
    currentUser() {
        return this.$store.state.user;
     }
 }
```

the thing which i want to explain. Two of these functions are get and two are option functions. Get functions show me the data twice.
[image]

As I said, if I use my Vuex file, it comes up twice on each page, but I want to process the data at once, how can I do this? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

When you use Vue/Vuex, your data will be stored in your state so you only need to get the state from computed. If your API call 2 times, it means you use it 2 times in your code. Just recheck.

Comment: You are right but without vuex I can't access the data. How can I access to data?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can learn more about mapState, mapGetters.

Comment: Hello, I can see the data from my global laravel 8 function on every page and I want to reach this data. Can I use this data without requesting the request again with the api?

Answer (score 0):

When using Vue with the state management tool Vuex, when you send json response from Laravel to Vue and invoke your mutation, data will be stored in state and you can retrieve it from there. Be sure to use a getter for fetching state.

See:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components

and:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

1. Try to use the Vue devtool chrome extension. It is very useful for debugging errors in Vue: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en
2. Make sure to call the getter only once; somewhere in your code you have called it twice, therefore it gets the user twice.